# Querying array sub-document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB in a `Node.js` app with `mongoose`. 
I have a collection in my DB, that can be described with the following schema:

```
{
  id: String,
  name: String,
  indicators: [{
    date: Date,
    value: Number
  }]
}
```

where `id` is unique, and each document has a lot of `indicators` in it.

I want to able to query the collection according to attributes of the `indicators` array. For example: sort the array by date or limit the amount of results in the array (possibly with an offset).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the number of items in the array with [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/). For example:

```
Model.find({}, { indicators: { $slice: 5 } }, function(err, data) {
    // ...
});
```

Will return the first 5 elements.

But if you want to sort it, then you will have to use the aggregation framework:

```
Model.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$indicators' },
    { $sort: { 'indicators.date': -1 } }
], function(err, data) { /* .... */ });
```